# Can I end a Stunt Run or Road Rage mission early?

Tags: burnout-paradise

If I meet the score or takedown requirements for a Stunt Run or Road Rage mission before the timer runs out, can I end the mission early and still get credit for completing the mission?

[image: Beating top score in a stunt run]

Comment: Never tried that, but I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can end a mission early by stopping the car and sitting still for around 5 seconds. Ending a Stunt Run or Road Rage mission early after meeting the requirements will count as a win.

Note: Stunt Run missions will not end if you have an active combo. You can either wait for the combo to run out or end the combo by wrecking your car.